# Kafka JDBC Connector with MSSQL only streams 100 rows

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-kafka, database-connection

I'm connecting to a Microsoft SQL Server database using the standard Confluent JDBC connector and Microsoft's JDBC driver. For one particular table, whether I set my `mode=timestamp` and give it a timestamp column or I just set it to `mode=bulk`, I only ever get 100 results. It never streams more than this. Here's what the end of my Connect log keeps spitting out:

```
[2018-09-19 12:51:51,393] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MES-0} Source task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:199)
[2018-09-19 12:51:51,412] INFO After filtering the tables are: "MES2ERP"."dbo"."BatchDetails" (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableMonitorThread:175)
[2018-09-19 12:51:51,412] INFO Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:868)
[2018-09-19 12:51:51,475] INFO Cluster ID: GMY7vibUSHGp5xRekGDEwg (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata:285)
[2018-09-19 12:52:51,069] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MES-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:397)
[2018-09-19 12:52:51,070] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MES-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:414)
[2018-09-19 12:52:51,077] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MES-0} Finished commitOffsets successfully in 7 ms (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:496)
[2018-09-19 12:53:51,082] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MES-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:397)
[2018-09-19 12:53:51,082] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MES-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:414)
```

I realize there is the `batch.max.rows` and the default is 100, but with `mode=timestamp`, I should get all rows in the table streamed, not stopping after 100. I would expect `bulk` would also eventually stream everything, or at least repeat the same 100 every `table.poll.interval.ms`, but it doesn't - it just stops. Any idea what's going on?

Oh, and my table has hundreds of thousands of rows in it.

**Here's my connector config**

```
name=JSON_OCN_MES-BatchDetails
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://####;databaseName=####;user=####;password=####;
table.whitelist=BatchDetails
mode=bulk
validate.non.null=false
topic.prefix=JSON_OCN_MES-
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the default (100) batch.max.rows setting within your connector

```
"batch.max.rows": "1234",
```